# Dictionary inside a dictionary in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have dictionary which has:

```
a = {'card1' :{'name':'abc','amount':'145820'},'card2':{'name':'dba','amount':'258963'}}
```

Now, I want to print `card1.amount` in Django template. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The Django template language allows you to do multiple lookups e.g. `{{ a.b.c.d }}`. In your example, it looks like you want `{{ a.card1.amount }}` in the template.

Comment: i tried with {{ a.card1.amount }} , but i didnt get anything

Comment: If that doesn't work you need to show your view. At the moment I can only guess what your template context is.

Comment: In my view i am sending the above  json to django  template . in template i want only the  amount in card1 and card2

Comment: Unless you show your view I can’t help. Your original question doesn’t mention JSON anywhere.

Comment: a = {'card1' :{'name':'abc','amount':'145820'},'card2':{'name':'dba','amount':'258963'}} return render(request,templatename.html,{'a':a})

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. Edit your original question. Note that `a` is a regular Python dictionary in your comment, it isn't JSON. For that code, `{{ a.card1.amount }}` in the template *would* work, so there must be something else in your real code that you are not showing.

Comment: @T_Torture please ask a new question, I can’t help in the comments. You can use `x.0` to get the first item in a list, so there is probably a different problem.